# При выводе в консоль массива он пустой, но нет (массив Шрёдингера)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-database

При обращении к firebase получаю response и заношу данные во внешний массив который был задан до этого, и все данные заносятся, но в консоле показывается [ ], но при открытии там есть все данные. Также при ображении по ключу выдает underfined.

Мой код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Консоль браузера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работаю с React.js и firebase realtime database.

Вопрос: Что вообще происходит, как исправить это?

Comment: Никогда не верьте объектам в консоли. В частности при разворачивании массива показывается его содержимое на момент разворачивания, а не на момент вывода в консоль.

Answer (score 3):

Запрос данных из БД это асинхронный код. `console.log` - это синхронный код. В момент выполнения `console.log` данные ещё не получены. А когда вы смотрит данные в консоли они уже там. Можно поставить `console.log` после цикла `for`, внутри коллбека.

Вот пример который иллюстрирует данное поведение:

```js
const result = [];

setTimeout(() => {
  result.push("value");
}, 0);

console.log(result);
console.log(result[0]);


//-------------------------------------

const result2 = [];

setTimeout(() => {
  result2.push("value");
  console.log(result2);
  console.log(result2[0]);
}, 0);
```